# Android - Header problems

Tags: android

After a long search I could not find an answer that suits my problems. I hope I'm not repeating any existing topic.

I have an Android app based on a website made with PHP and mysql. To collect the data I'm using an ArrayList and to display it an adapter in which I add later the header. This is my code:

```
public void run() {
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            Verpaiseur.this, paisesList,
            R.layout.tablapaiseur, new String[]{TAG_PID, TAG_PAIS, TAG_TOTAL},
            new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.paiseur, R.id.cantidadeur});

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
}
```

1) Is it possible in an easy way to have this header fixed at the top? I mean not scrollable

2) As I have many screens with shows long lists, is it possible to set an array with the title strings and use it at addHeaderView. I mean, addHeaderView(header, array, false);

Thank you very much in advance

Here it is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="6dip"
android:paddingBottom="6dip"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/paiseur"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/cantidadeur"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: to answer 1. how are you designing the activity's layout? in the xml, why not just put a static linearlayout on top of the listview?

Comment: I have added the layout. Thank you fr your quick reply